# Build Fails Missing File Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a brand new Visual Studio 2015 project stored in a TFS Git repo. I've configured a build using the standard Default Git build template.  The new project builds locally just fine, but fails during the TFS Build with the following error:

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props.
```

Answer (score 0):

When TFS first creates your Git repository, it includes a default .gitIgnore file which "hides" certain files from your your (Pending) Changes window.  One of the wildcard based exclusions in the default .gitIgnore file specifically excludes any files from being checked in under any folder that includes "build/"  which includes this specific file.  For now, I've commented out that exclusion in the file, and now it shows up in my (pending) Changes window.

[image]

Comment: How about ignoring "packages/" (which includes the unwanted build folder) in your .gitignore?